# Unpacking a list of list of list

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

The current input I use in my program is a list of list of coordinates:

```
data = [["D_02", "10", "10", "20"],
         ["X_03", "10", "10", "20"]]
```

For ease of use and convenience, I would like to be able to pass a list of list of list as well:

`have`:

```
data = [[["B_01"], ["10"], ["10", "20"], ["10", "20"]],
             ["D_02", "10", "10", "20"],
             ["X_03", "10", "10", "20"]]
```

and then be able to "explode" it to make it like the following:

`want`:

```
data = [["B_01", "10", "10", "10"],
        ["B_01", "10", "10", "20"],
        ["B_01", "10", "20", "10"],
        ["B_01", "10", "20", "20"],
        ["D_02", "10", "10", "20"],
        ["X_03", "10", "10", "20"]]
```

I know it is possible to do so for a list of list with the `product` function of the `itertools` package:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.product(*data))
```

However,

1. How can I do the same for a list of list of list ?
2. How can I loop on the input to only explode the list of list of list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.product` only if the first item of row is a list:

```
final = []
for l in data:
    if isinstance(l[0], list):  # <- ["B01"]
        for c in itertools.product(*l[1:]):
            final.append(l[0] + list(c))
    else:
        final.append(l)
```

```
>>> final
[['B_01', '10', '10', '10'],
 ['B_01', '10', '10', '20'],
 ['B_01', '10', '20', '10'],
 ['B_01', '10', '20', '20'],
 ['D_02', '10', '10', '20'],
 ['X_03', '10', '10', '20']]
```

Comment: I think this wouldn't work when the first element is a list and it contains more than one element.